# How to compare multiple textboxes and fire validator if they arent equal c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, comparevalidator

The issue I have is that I need a way to compare the values from 4 textboxes input by user with another 6 textboxes input by user. If they dont match then fire validation to stop progress. I use a label called 'lblH1' to show they need to match textboxes. Is it possible to use compare validator or ranger validator controls to do this?

```
h1_total = Convert.ToInt32(txtKS_1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtKS_2.Text) + 
           Convert.ToInt32(txtKS_3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtKS_4.Text);

H2A_total = Convert.ToInt32(txtH2A_1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtH2A_2.Text) + 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtH2A_3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtH2A_4.Text) +
            Convert.ToInt32(txtH2A_5.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtH2A_6.Text);

if (h1_total == H2A_total)
{ 
    //save
}
else
{
    lblH1.Visible = true;
    lblH1.Text= "Values must match";
}
```

Comment: you want to validate it client side or server side?
do you want to do it by using JavaScript?

Comment: do you want to validate the values in textboxes or the sum of those values? in code you are comparing sum.

Comment: Sorry server side if I can - dont really know enugh Javascript

Comment: Yeah i want to take total sum from 4 textboxes (h1_total) and compare this with 6 textboxes (H2A_total ) to see if they match

Comment: @wubblyjuggly then whats wrong with your code, its fine if you want to validate it server side.

Comment: It isnt an elegant way of doing it below way is prob better for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `CustomValidator` for this, like shown below

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function validate(sender, arg) {
            debugger;
            var h1_total =
                (document.getElementById("txtKS_1").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtKS_1").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtKS_2").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtKS_2").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtKS_3").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtKS_3").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtKS_4").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtKS_4").value));

            var H2A_total =
                (document.getElementById("txtH2A_1").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtH2A_1").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtH2A_2").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtH2A_2").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtH2A_3").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtH2A_3").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtH2A_4").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtH2A_4").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtH2A_5").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtH2A_5").value)) +
                (document.getElementById("txtH2A_6").value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtH2A_6").value));

            if (h1_total != H2A_total)
                arg.IsValid = false;
            else
                arg.IsValid = true;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtKS_1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtKS_2" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtKS_3" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtKS_4" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtH2A_1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtH2A_2" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtH2A_3" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtH2A_4" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtH2A_5" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtH2A_6" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <br />
            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="vali1" ErrorMessage="Values must be same." ClientValidationFunction="validate" ValidationGroup="validate" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Click me" ValidationGroup="validate" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Things to be noted:

I have used `ClientIDMode="Static"` just for the sake of making code compact, please ignore it if you can and use `document.getElementById('<%= txtH2A_6.ClientID %>')` etc.